# Take photo of pre-formatted screen and extract specific data

Tags: mobile, camera, ocr, screen-scraping

Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question.  Is there fairly straightforward way to write an app that will use the Camera (for example iOS) to take a photo of a pre-formatted screen and recognize / retrieve that data?

This isn't a top secret project or anything, so I'll be happy to share as many details as necessary.  Basically my electric car displays a pop-up with stats when it turns off.  Since there aren't any OEM apps that track things like charging, I guess I have to do it manually.  I figured, since the screen is always the same, perhaps it would be possible to aim the camera "just right" using an app that could look for certain data in certain places.  The way a shopping app looks for barcodes or Apple Wallet reads credit card numbers.

Is this a dumb idea?  If it's easy and you'll make a million bucks selling the app, then feel free to steal it.  I'll be your first customer.  In the meantime, is this doable by a random jackass who's way over his head when it comes to programming?  :-)

For example, if I could just grab Energy Used and Miles driven, then I'm sure I could programmatically get other data like date/time from the device taking the picture.  Here is one example.

['energy used' popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuYTF.jpg) Sample screen 001.

Comment: I guess I should say that "taking a picture" (ie storing a photo file on the device) isn't specifically what I'm after.  Just using the camera for input.

Comment: Thank you!  I will do more research with your links!